# Python can't parse my list of ints

Tags: python

Im having some problem with a list of ints, it looks like this:

[image]

Its part of a bigger list, but when I try to go thru it line by line and parse it I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xef\xbb\xbf85\n'
```

My code looks like:

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as ins:

    array = []

    for line in ins:
        print 'String: ', line

        print 'Integer: ', int(line)
```

If I try to catch the error with this code:

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as ins:

    array = []

    for line in ins:
        print 'String: ', line

        try:
            print 'Integer: ', int(line)
        except:
            print 'Non-integer: ', line
```

I get this output:

[image]

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Can you post text as text, not as screenshots please?

Comment: Looks like some of your lines contain secret invisible unicode characters. You should remove those before trying to convert to integer.

Comment: bingo BOM header!

Comment: use `strip(line)`

Comment: Your line variable has "\n" also.Strip it .

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Actually try `int('2\n')`, it works, `int` ignores whitespace

Comment: @Ev.Kounis strip is a function in a library? line.strip() does not solve anything for me :(